# Spring Boot 1.4.2 + Jetty fails on startup with NullPointerException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to run Spring Boot application with Jetty. The following exception is thrown during startup. The pom.xml is configured according to docs. What do I miss?

INFO Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
WARN Failed startup of context o.s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@3fbfa96{/,file:///C:/Users/.../AppData/Loc
al/Temp/jetty-docbase.7799235456508385695.8081/,UNAVAILABLE}
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplication
Context.java:229)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationCont
ext.java:89)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationCon
text.java:213)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration$Initializer.callInitia
lizers(ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.java:83)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration$Initializer.doStart(Se
rvletContextInitializerConfiguration.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:809)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1404)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1366)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:778)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:520)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:422)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:389)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(JettyEmbeddedServlet
Container.java:91)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.(JettyEmbeddedServletCont
ainer.java:79)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getJettyEmbeddedServletC
ontainer(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:540)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContai
ner(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(Embedd
edWebApplicationContext.java:164)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationConte
xt.java:134)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext
.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
        at com.ebs.mytreasury.frontend.FrontendApplication.main(FrontendApplication.java:68)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:521)
INFO Started @13219ms

Comment: I found the problem cause. It was my fault. I used

Comment: @Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean requestDumperFilter()

Comment: return null; :)